# In which directory are functions executed when using the Matlab Compiler?

Tags: matlab, file, logging

I have a batch program written in Matlab, which will be deployed to a production system by packaging it using the Compiler Toolbox.

When starting the program, multiple config and data files will be loaded, where the first config file contains paths and filenames for the other files to be loaded. I have a logger in the form of a hidden global object, and its static functions allow to add to the log. Every line will be immediately written to file (Performance does not matter, but reliable logging does!).

I want to dynamically specify the location of the logfile in a text file, but I don't know where I should put that file. In the classic interpreter mode, the wd of the constructor within the loggers' classdef seems to be directory where the file is saved, but I don't really understand why.

What is a reliable way of finding a textfile in the same directory as my classdef in a Compiler-packaged program using relative paths?

Thanks!

Comment: Define "reliable". It's a bit vague what you are asking here.

Comment: I need to find a file that determines the path to a Logfile. I'm not sure where to put that file, and while my first guess is that the same directory as the classdef would be correct, I'm not sure how to link to that, considering Matlab often switches directories, and I'm using the Compiler to package the program. Ideal would be a full static path (C:\Logs\log.txt), but I need some flexibility, so I would like to have a relative path to a file that specifies the path to the logfile.